# itertools.takewhile within a generator function - why is it evaluated once only?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I have a text file like this:

```
11
2
3
4

11

111
```

Using Python 2.7, I want to turn it into a list of lists of lines, where line breaks divide items in the inner list and empty lines divide items in the outer list. Like so:

```
[["11","2","3","4"],["11"],["111"]]
```

And for this purpose, I wrote a generator function that would yield the inner lists one at a time once passed an open file object:

```
def readParag(fileObj):
    currentParag = []
    for line in fileObj:
        stripped = line.rstrip()
    if len(stripped) > 0: currentParag.append(stripped)
    elif len(currentParag) > 0:
        yield currentParag
        currentParag = []
```

That works fine, and I can call it from within a list comprehension, producing the desired result. However, it subsequently occurred to me that I might be able to do the same thing more concisely using `itertools.takewhile` (with a view to rewriting the generator function as a generator expression, but we'll leave that for now). This is what I tried:

```
from itertools import takewhile    
def readParag(fileObj):
    yield [ln.rstrip() for ln in takewhile(lambda line: line != "\n", fileObj)]
```

In this case, the resulting generator yields only one result (the expected first one, i.e. `["11","2","3","4"]`). I had hoped that calling its `next` method again would cause it to evaluate `takewhile(lambda line: line != "\n", fileObj)` again on the remainder of the file, thus leading it to yield another list. But no: I got a `StopIteration` instead. So I surmised that the `take while` expression was being evaluated once only, at the time when the generator object was created, and not each time I called the resultant generator object's `next` method.

This supposition made me wonder what would happen if I called the generator function again. The result was that it created a new generator object that also yielded a single result (the expected second one, i.e. `["11"]`) before throwing a `StopIteration` back at me. So in fact, writing this as a generator function effectively gives the same result as if I'd written it as an ordinary function and `return`ed the list instead of `yield`ing it.

I guess I could solve this problem by creating my own class to use instead of a generator (as in John Millikin's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376438/how-to-make-a-repeating-generator-in-python)). But the point is that I was hoping to write something *more concise than* my original generator function (possibly even a generator expression). Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong, and how to get it right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a perfect job for [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def read_parag(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for k,g in groupby((line.strip() for line in f), bool):
            if k:
                yield list(g)
```

which will give:

```
>>> list(read_parag('myfile.txt')
[['11', '2', '3', '4'], ['11'], ['111']]
```

Or in one line:

```
[list(g) for k,g in groupby((line.strip() for line in open('myfile.txt')), bool) if k]
```

Comment: Use `bool` instead of the `lambda`, and `yield` the results instead of appending them to a list -- otherwise nice! =)

Comment: +1 out of jealousy. I wrote a version of this as a genexp but didn't think of passing groupby the stripped lines, so I had `.strip()` in two places and I didn't like the look of it.  You win this round!

Comment: @DSM, would you mind posting the generator expression you came up with for comparison?

Comment: @RikPoggi: I think that `g` would do for `list(g)` and that there's a missing closing parenthesis after the `open` function call in your one-liner (i.e.: `[g for k,g in groupby((line.strip() for line in open("myfile.txt")), bool) if k]`). Otherwise, you've answered my question! Thanks!

Comment: @Westcroft_to_Apse: your sample output was showing a list of lists. If your actual case is different (example: you may just need a one time consuming iterator) change what you need to. The missing `)` was a typo, fixed it.

Comment: @RikPoggi: you're right of course about that. From the point of view of my actual case, an iterator was better than lists - I'd forgotten that in my example I'd specifically mentioned lists.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers do a good job of explaining what is going on here, you need to call `takewhile` multiple times which your current generator does not do.  Here is a fairly concise way to get the behavior you want using the built-in [`iter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) function with a sentinel argument:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def readParag(fileObj):
    cond = lambda line: line != "\n"
    return iter(lambda: [ln.rstrip() for ln in takewhile(cond, fileObj)], [])
```

Comment: Thanks very much! The answer I've chosen is slightly more concise (using `groupby` instead of `takewhile`), but I'm grateful for your demonstration that the best way to get `takewhile` to work in this context is to use the `iter` function rather than a generator.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly how `.takewhile()` should behave. While the condition is true, it'll return elements from the underlying iterable, and as soon as it's false, it *permamently* switches to the iteration-done stage.

Note that this is how iterators must behave; raising StopIteration means just that, stop iterating over me, I am done.

From the [python glossary on "iterator"](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterator):

> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the iterator’s `next()` method return successive items in the stream. When no more data are available a `StopIteration` exception is raised instead. At this point, the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to its `next()` method just raise `StopIteration` again.

You could combine `takewhile` with `tee` to see if there are any more results in the next batch:

```
import itertools

def readParag(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        while True:
            paras = itertools.takewhile(lambda l: l.strip(), f)
            test, paras = itertools.tee(paras)
            test.next()  # raises StopIteration when the file is done
            yield (l.strip() for l in paras)
```

This yields generators, so each item yielded is itself a generator. You do need to consume all elements in these generators for this to continue to work; the same is true for the groupby method listed in another answer.

Comment: This. On that note, a possible fix would be to call `takewhile()` again each time a newline is detected.

Comment: Thanks, Martijn - that's helpful. Do you know if there is an equivalent of `.takewhile` that *doesn't* permanently switch to the 'iteration-done' stage, so that I can make my one-liner work as I want it to? Or should I just stick with my original generator function and be thankful that it gets the job done?

Comment: Use `groupby()`, as in Rik Poggi's answer.

Comment: @JAB: I used a different method, actually.

Comment: @JAB Rik Poggi's answer is great, but unless I'm missing something (entirely possible!) it looks too complicated to re-write as a generator expression, so I'm still wondering whether something like my one-liner can be made to work?

Comment: @Westcroft_to_Apse: simply replace `yield list(g)` with `yield g`. :-)

Comment: @Westcroft_to_Apse: or if you'd like here's in one line: `[list(g) for k,g in groupby((line.strip() for line in open('myfile.txt'), bool) if k]`

Comment: @RikPoggi: Thanks - that's really helpful and I'm going to check out `groupby` for future work. Would you mind pasting that into your original answer so it can be found more easily?

Comment: Your one-liner is a list expression, Rik. `(list(g) for k,g in groupby((line.strip() for line in open('myfile.txt'), bool) if k)` would be the generator equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

If the file contents fit into memory, there is a much easier way to get the groups separated by blank lines:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    groups = [group.split() for group in f.read().split("\n\n")]
```

This approach can be made more robust by using `re.split()` instead of `str.split()` and by filtering out potential empty groups resulting from four or more consecutive line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

This is the documented behavior of `takewhile`.  It takes *while* the condition is true.  It doesn't start up again if the condition later becomes true again.

The simple fix is to make your function just call takewhile in a loop, stopping when takewhile has nothing more to return (i.e., at the end of the file):

```
def readParag(fileObj):
    while True:      
        nextList = [ln.rstrip() for ln in takewhile(lambda line: line != "\n", fileObj)]
        if not nextList:
            break
        yield nextList
```

Comment: This is what I has failed to understand when I asked the question! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call takewhile multiple times:

```
>>> def readParagGenerator(fileObj):
...     group = [ln.rstrip() for ln in takewhile(lambda line: line != "\n", fileObj)]
...     while len(group) > 0:
...         yield group
...         group = [ln.rstrip() for ln in takewhile(lambda line: line != "\n", fileObj)]
... 
>>> list(readParagGenerator(StringIO(F)))
[['11', '2', '3', '4'], ['11'], ['111']]
```

Comment: `while group` will do just fine too.